# Drupal twig suggestions is not overriden

Tags: theming

I am overriding twig suggestions for node, but it sometimes happen and sometimes not, I have added this code in my `.theme` file.

```

```
function mediumish_blog_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if ($route_name == "entity.taxonomy_term.canonical" && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'node__view__taxonomy_term';
  } elseif (preg_match("/^view.archive.*$/", $route_name)) {
    $parameter = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('arg_0');
    if ($parameter != null) {
      $suggestions[] = 'node__view__archive_month';
    }
  }
}
```

```

Comment: And the suggestions are what, listed in the html source?

Comment: They are default ones.. like `node--view--frontend.html.twig, * node--22--teaser.html.twig, node--22.html.twig, node--blog--teaser.html.twig, node--blog.html.twig, node--teaser.html.twig, node.html.twig`

Comment: I don't understand the `$tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->...` part in your code, are you sure you want to use the assignment operator in your if-statement? The `$tid` variable isn't used anywhere. Maybe you can explain what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I think i made mistake there.. let me check, Thanks

Comment: I fixed that but still i am getting the same error, Every time i added new content, i need to clear cache to make my new content to  get my custom suggestion and adopt that new suggestion.